# Why jquery on .html(data) with data='<script src >...' shows incorrect result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Why jquery on .html(data) with

```
data='<sript src>...'
```

shows incorrect result?
For example:
http://dev.khartn.name/
Click on the "Full Text Search Programm Complex." in the right column.

```
function loadPage(link) {
$.get(link, function(data) {
    $("#blogsss").fadeOut("200", function () {
        $("#pleasewait").fadeIn("200", function() {
//                alert(data);
            $('#blogsss').html(data);
            $("#pleasewait").fadeOut("200", function() {
                $("#blogsss").fadeIn("200", function(){
                    SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
                    return true;
                });
            });
        });
    });
}).error(function() {
    alert("Error loading page, please check your Internet connection and try again.");
    $("#pleasewait").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#blogsss").fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
});
}
```

If in the response will sent some html text, then all right.
But if in the response html text plus javascript, like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ru/js/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vaGxvaC5uZXQvcC80ODgxNTIvd2lkZ2V0cy9wcm9qZWN0X2xhbmd1YWdlcy5qcw==">
</script>
```

result will be show incorrectly - shows only the response from the script src.

How to fix this bug?

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: How is it working incorrectly? Do you see a javascript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try `jQuery.load`

```
$('#a').load('article.html');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .html() strips out any script tags. Using the native .innerHTML can help you overcome this issue if you really want to inject scripts into the page like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I already have to try to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ , but effect is same. As I understand it, called a script that contains the document.write, is applied to the root of the document.

Comment: Called script applyed to the <body>

Comment: As I see it the (regardless the security and talking about separation of concerns now) your javascript is in the wrong place. The page your calling via ajax shouldn't contain embeded javascript unless it is a source code. Instead of putting the javascript code in the page you are loading, put it in the main page and call the function in the ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't supposed to do that, it would expose security issues, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.

You should rather ask the script content separately. You can use the method `$.getScript` for it, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: It's not security issue. JavaScript src file is on the my domain. I already have to try to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ , but effect is same. As I understand it, called a script that contains the document.write, is applied to the root of the document.

Comment: Called script applyed to the <body>